# CSS effect (shadow, stroke) on SVG with different sizes

Tags: php, vector, svg, size, stroke

i have a problem with SVGs (different sizes) and effetcs (strokes, shadows etc.)
The stroke (for example) has not the same size because the icon B is smaller and it is "zoomed" to 500px.

**What is the correct way to fix this issue?**

- must i calculate the effect for every SVG individually? :/
- or is there an option to only zoom the SVG and not the effect?
- or can i recalculate (with PHP) the SVGs? So that every SVG has the same size?

**FIDDLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/tqef7qkp/

**CSS**

```
stroke: #39A02E;  
stroke-width: 5;
```

**Example**
[image: example]

---

**A)**

```
<svg xml:space="preserve" 
preserveAspectRatio= "xMinYMin meet" 
enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" 
viewBox="0 0 500 500" 
width="500px" 
height="500px" 
y="0px" 
x="0px" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
```

---

**B)**

```
<svg xml:space="preserve"
preserveAspectRatio= "xMinYMin meet" 
enable-background="new 0 0 50 50" 
viewBox="0 0 50 50" 
width="500px" 
height="500px" 
y="0px" 
x="0px" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify stroke-widths in percentages, not just userSpace units. You can also specify shadow filters the same way (in objectBoundingBox units). This will size your strokes to the size of your svg's vs. the size of your viewboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css" >
  <![CDATA[
   g {  stroke: #39A02E;  
   stroke-width: 1;  
   fill:url(#rgrad);}
  ]]>
</style>
```

That could fix the stroke problem.

The output: [image]

Comment: So the best (and clean) way is to calculate the stroke, shadows for every SVG individually? Not really comfortable :/

Comment: I don't achieve your problem maybe, but if you have multiple "<path d=" in the svg file, each path will have the same stroke as declared in the css part.
You should post all the svg source so i could understand better your problem, and can maybe help you in a better way.

Comment: The problem is the size, look at the viewBox. Icon A viewBox="0 0 500 500" and icon B viewBox="0 0 50 50". All my SVG has a diffrent size. Icon C viewBox="0 0 120 120", icon D viewBox="0 0 330 330" etc.
When i now resize the icon to 500px500px (with the SVG attr. width and height) the stroke is resized too.

Comment: You could try to add the size of svg image and the stroke in a external css file, and call it from your path. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tqef7qkp/1/